How to load external msg.properties for MessageBundle?
I'm using Qute with Quarkus and defined my messages/msg.properties file. It works as expected. What I'm trying to achive is to load msg.properties file from external configuration.
Based on this article Config Sources when running native app I've added my properties file to $PWD/config/ folder - so it is under $PWD/config/messages/msg.properties. Unfortunately this is still not loaded.
How could I achive to load properties from external source?

Define multiple location as described in the page https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#locations

Additionally to the default config locations, Quarkus provides a way to scan additional locations for configuration properties files.


The quarkus.config.locations configuration property accepts multiple locations separated by a comma , and each must represent a valid URI. The supported URI schemes are:

file or directory (file:)
classpath resource
jar resource (jar:)
http resource (http:)


As long as process user has access to those paths defined in quarkus.config.locations it should work. Example
quarkus.config.locations=management/organization/security/datasource.properties,management/organization/security/network.properties

Check here for more examples.
